# How to you include a OneHotEncoder step in a saved model to deploy via Flask?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have an XGBoost model that predicts whether a student will enter college based on a number of features. Part of the model is using OneHotEncoder to transform a few columns with string values. There's nothing wrong with the model, but I've run into issues with building a rudimentary Flask app that takes in a JSON to make a prediction. My confusion is where I add the OneHotEncoder step? Would I need to re-build the model using a pipeline for OneHotEncoding, model parameters, and fitting, save the model again, and then when I send the JSON via Postman, the saved model will put the data through the OneHotEncoder step? Can I add OneHotEncoder as part of the GridSearchCV step?

```
optimal_params = GridSearchCV(
    estimator = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='binary:logistic'),
    param_grid=param_grid,
    scoring='roc_auc',
    verbose=2,
    n_jobs=10,
    cv=3
)
optimal_params.fit(X, 
               y,
              early_stopping_rounds=10,
              eval_metric='auc',
              eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
              verbose=False)
```

Flask code:

```
def return_prediction(college_model, sample_json):

    type_school = sample_json["type_school"]
    school_accreditation = sample_json["school_accreditation"]
    gender = sample_json['gender']
    interest = sample_json['interest']
    residence = sample_json['residence']
    parent_age = sample_json['parent_age']
    parent_salary = sample_json['parent salary']
    house_area = sample_json['house_area']
    average_grades = sample_json['average_grades']
    parent_was_in_college = sample_json['parent_was_in_college']


    college = [[type_school, school_accreditation, gender, interest, 
          residence, parent_age, parent_salary, house_area, 
          average_grades, parent_was_in_collegel]]



    class_ind = college_model.predict(college)

    return class_ind


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return '<h1>Flask Running</h>'


college_model = joblib.load("college_model.pkl")
column_trans = joblib.load("ohe.pkl")


@app.route('/college', methods=['POST'])
def prediction():
    content = request.json
    results = return_predictions(college_model, column_trans, content)
    results = results.tolist()
    return jsonify(results)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

After GridSearchCV, you will store the final variable and make the model for it into a pkl file.

And you have to put in the preprocessing part of your flask code.

The data should be OneHotEncode as possible so that it can be predicated.

```
def return_prediction(college_model, sample_json):

    type_school = sample_json["type_school"]
    school_accreditation = sample_json["school_accreditation"]
    gender = sample_json['gender']
    interest = sample_json['interest']
    residence = sample_json['residence']
    parent_age = sample_json['parent_age']
    parent_salary = sample_json['parent salary']
    house_area = sample_json['house_area']
    average_grades = sample_json['average_grades']
    parent_was_in_college = sample_json['parent_was_in_college']


    college = [[type_school, school_accreditation, gender, interest, 
          residence, parent_age, parent_salary, house_area, 
          average_grades, parent_was_in_collegel]]

    colleage['in your str data'] = pd.get_dummies(colleage = columns = ['in your str data'])


    class_ind = college_model.predict(college)

    return class_ind
```

Comment: Something like:
        column_trans = make_column_transformer(
        (OneHotEncoder(), ['type_school','school_accreditation',
                  'gender','interest','residence','parent_was_in_college']),
        remainder='passthrough')   

    column_trans.fit_transform(college)